# OSX Terminal reverted using Vim 7.2 after I installed 7.3 from macports

Tags: macos, vim, macports

I installed Vim 7.3 via MacPorts, and it worked great. However, after I closed Terminal and came back to it, I found out after a little bit that it had reverted to the old 7.2. How do I remove the old, default vim in OSX or force it to use the macports version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a problem with your $PATH variable. Check to verify that the vim7.3 install path is in your $PATH variable. If it is make sure it is before the install path for vim7.2.

The vim installer probably set an environment variable for your current shell that isn't in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

Comment: Instead I made a symlink to the macports version and that works great. I'd be willing to accept yours as the answer, but I'll wait to see if you or others would give a "best practices" opinion. What I mean is, should I just remove the old vim via $ rm /usr/bin/vim-bak? What about other macports? Do I add the path every time I have a conflict? It sounds a little dodgy, so I want to know the best way.

Comment: This answer is the best practice. `/opt/local/bin` should be in your `$PATH` if you're interested in using MacPorts.

Comment: Nope, adding it to the path doesn't work. Even though vim7.3 is indeed in the /opt/local/bin, osx wants to use the vim7.2 in /usr/bin (and yes, I did source my .bash_profile and verify by echo $PATH).

Comment: I would remove the old vim. Here's what I dow with git. When I install and build a new git it goes in a totally new directory and I update the symlink. This is all taken care of in a script that downlaods git, builds, installs, and updates the symlink.

Comment: What do you mean by 'osx wants to use the vim7.2 in /usr/bin' what action do you do

Comment: Where did you add `/opt/local/bin`? To the start or end of your path? If you added it at the end, your shell will find the old vim first, and use that. (i.e. do `PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH` not `PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin`)

Comment: Duh. That did it. I've been using linux and the command line for a decade and didn't realize that's how it worked. If I could give the question to you I would, but Mark deserves it too. Thanks to everyone--I learned something useful through this dialogue.